# Using aggregators (Min, Max, Avg) inside South migrations

Tags: python, django, django-south, database-migration

I want to perform `annotate`/`aggregate` inside migration, because my data needs to be prepared before schema modifications. South does not permit import aggregators fro `django.db.models` - it throws an error on migration application stage. So is there some way to do this in South?

Comment: What do you mean by `annotate`/`aggregate`?

Comment: Check this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: You can always write a custom command as outlined here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run it using `python manage.py custom_aggregate_command`. Also, take a look at this: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a worst case scenario, but one option would be to make South just exec the SQL directly for you.

From their docs: https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/databaseapi.html#db-execute

Getting the SQL query sometimes can be a pain, but you can make Django just give it to you from your `Model.objects.filter().blahblah.blah` statement

### Fair warning

Messing about with a query object like this directly is bad so please don't do that in your deployed code. In this case though since `.aggregate()` doesn't return a QuerySet it's a bit harder to get at the actual query. With that said, to get the SQL from your query (assuming it's somewhat easy to isolate the whole thing) you can fire up a `django-admin.py shell` and do something like

```python
from django.db.models import Count
import MyModel

q = MyModel.objects.all().query
q.add_aggregate(Count('pk'), MyModel, 'name', is_summary=True)
print q
```

### It's easier for annotate

`.annotate()` returns a queryset directly so you don't have to muck about with `.add_aggregate()`.

```python
from django.db.models import Count
import MyModel

print (MyModel.objects.all()
       .annotate(c = Count('some_field'))
       .query)
```

### Meanwhile, in South

From there you pretty much cut-n-paste that SQL into a string for your data migration, and then call `db.execute`. The rest of the error handling and rollback stuff is very dependent on your situation, but I'd strongly recommend writing a rollback just to be safe.